# String Security <security:authorize url="..."> и @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-security

Добрый день. Работаю со Spring Security 4. Профиль может редактировать только его хозяин или администратор. Имею следующий код в контроллере (`UserDetails` переопределен и имеет поле `uid`):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or "
        + "(isAuthenticated() and principal.uid == #personId)")
@RequestMapping(path = "/persons/uid{personId}/edit",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editPerson(@PathVariable Integer personId, Model model) {
    getPerson(personId, model);
    return "editPerson";
}
```

и на JSP-странице просмотре профиля:

```
<c:url value="/persons/uid${person.uid}/edit" var="editUrl" />
<sec:authorize url="${editUrl}">
    <a href="${editUrl}">Редактировать</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

Ссылка показывается всем. Однако, при отсутствии нужных прав (`uid != 1` или неавторизированный пользователь), доступ на страницу `persons/uid1/edit` запрещен, то есть тут `@PreAuthorize` работает.

Подскажите, в чем дело?

Comment: А что не работает?